# player for beamer to see slide translations

Tags: beamer

I am looking for a free player for beamer to see slide translations. for commands like for `\transwipe` , `\transblindsvertical`

Comment: [Free as in beer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free_as_in_beer): Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Thank you. My one didn't work, but I will try again. thanks.

Comment: You must put the viewer into Full Screen mode.